# Python Library to Generate VCF Files?

Tags: python, vcf-vcard

Know of any good libraries for this?  I did some searches and didn't come across anything.  Someone somewhere must have done this before, I hate to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would look at:

[http://vobject.skyhouseconsulting.com/usage.html](http://vobject.skyhouseconsulting.com/) (look under "Usage examples")

Very easy parsing and generation of both vCal and vCard.

Answer (score 2):

PyCoCuMa appears to have a VCF parser built into it, and it'll generate VCard output. You might have some luck with it. I played around with it a bit; it parsed some VCF files I have lying around without any problems. You'll most likely have to poke through the source to figure out how to use it, though.

See:

http://www.srcco.de/v/pycocuma

http://pycocuma.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.4.5-6-5/vcard_8py-source.html